# How to perform a train, test and validation set to predict

Tags: r, validation, machine-learning, classification, training-data

I have a really large dataset and i'm trying to build a classification model using R. 
However I need to use a train, test and validation set. But i'm a bit confused about the way to perform this. For example, I built a tree using a train set and then i computed the predicion using a test set. But I believe that i should be using the train and the test set to best tune the tree and after that use the validation set to validate. How can i do this?

```
library(rpart)
part.installed <- rpart(TARGET ~  RS_DESC+SAP_STATUS +                         
ACTIVATION_STATUS+ROTUL_STATUS+SIM_STATUS+RATE_PLAN_SEGMENT_NORM,
trainSet, method="class")

part.predictions <- predict(part.installed, testSet, type="class")
```

(P.S the tree is only an example. It could be another classification algorithm)

Comment: I'm not super familiar with ML terminology but I think that test sets and validation sets refer to the same thing. You would train on the training set and tune parameters to minimise error in the test/validation set.

Comment: My view of the language: you start by splitting off the *test set* before you do anything else (such as preprocessing); you will use the *test set* just once, at the very end of the whole process to *test* your model.  With what remains (the *training set*) you can create a *validation set*, or several if you are doing *cross-validation*, and you will use this to *tune* the *hyperparameters* for your model.  After having fixed the hyperparameters, you can use the whole *training set* for your *final model*.  You can finally *test* your final model against your *test set*.

Comment: If your test set performs badly, you should not start again with the same data, since your test set would turn into a validation set and could lead to overfitting

Comment: Your interpretation of training/test/validation is correct as far as I know.  I Have some questions:  what type of classification are you trying to perform?  Binary or >2 classes?  how many cases and how many features do you have?  What type of data? categorical, continuous or mixed?

Comment: I have  a subset with 1.334.377 observations. My target has 5 classes to predict (E,I,A,S,P). Refering to my independent variables, one is continuous and the rest of them are categorical.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the terminology is as follows:

1. The training set is used to build the classifier
2. The validation set is used to tune the algorithm hyperparameters *repeatedly*. So there will be some overfitting here, but that is why there is another stage:
3. The test set must not be touched until the classifier is *final* to prevent overfitting. It serves to **estimate the true accuracy**, if you would put the model into production.

Comment: Ok, but could you please give me an example with code in R showing how can I use the validation set to tune the algorithm?